# What happens to the DC when I free a canvas?

Tags: delphi, canvas, gdi

In this code I would expect a call to `ReleaseDC` to happen in `MyCanvas.Free`, but this code runs fine, how come?
And what happens to TCanvas' own DC?

```
var GlobalDC: THandle;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
   GlobalDC:= GetDC(0);
end;

function LoopMeOften(const X, Y: Integer): TColor;
var
  MyCanvas: TCanvas;
begin
  MyCanvas := TCanvas.Create;
  MyCanvas.Handle := GlobalDC;
  Result := GetPixel(MyCanvas.Handle, X, Y);
  MyCanvas.Free;
end;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`TCanvas` does not have its own DC, it neither acquires nor releases a DC. Its descendant `TControlCanvas` does.

From [TCanvas.Handle Property](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/Graphics_TCanvas_Handle.html)

> TCanvas does not own the HDC.
>   Applications must create an HDC and
>   set the Handle property. Applications
>   must release the HDC when the canvas
>   no longer needs it.